# htaccess rewriterule for aliasses

Tags: htaccess

On our main domain we are running a CMS which feeds several domains with different input.
The domains are directed with A records to the main ip address. The htaccess works fine it will bring up the right pages if you type in a url, lets say `www.ictzorg.nl`
It will show the url `www.ictzorg.nl` in your browser which is originally `www.ckc-seminars.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL`

This is the htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ictzorg.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ckc-seminars.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/$1 [P]
```

Problem now is that if you click on a link on that page it will search for

```
www.ictzorg.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/Page/450
```

It should direct to

```
www.ckc-seminars.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/Page/450
```

and should be shown in the URL bar as

```
www.ictzorg.nl/Page/450
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow? Isn't this dependent on how you are constructing the links on the page?

Comment: Hi, thats why I ask here I am really not into this. I seemed to me it must be doable with htaccess. there are always those 4 variables, Event/name_event/year/country

What after the country name comes is always unique for each event.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite rule you've written modifies both the domain, and the path, but you haven't updated the path in your page source.

You change `ictzorg.nl` to `http://www.ckc-seminars.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/`.  Fine, that works.

But the link in the page source is: `/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/Page/451`.

As it's a relative link, `www.ictzorg.nl` (the current domain in the browser) gets added to the front of it.

When it's clicked on, your rewrite rule then converts the `www.ictzorg.nl` to `http://www.ckc-seminars.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/` again.

So the final url ends up having part repeated, like:
`http://www.ckc-seminars.nl/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/Page/451`

**Solution:** get rid of the `/Event/ictzorg/2013/NL/` at the start of each URL in the source of the page (or with an extra rewrite rule), because your rewrite rule will put it back.